# How does variables works with the new Atooma SDK?

Tags: android, atooma

I'm working on an app plugin using the **Atooma SDK**. (it's in beta phase, you get the file by invitation here: http://sdk.atooma.com/#/ ) 
Is there anyone on a similar project? I have browsed the documentation but something is still unclear to me.

How does variables works? Are they added to a component (e.g. A trigger)? And can they be used just by *getVariables()*? 
The use of variables is intended only within the plugin itself?
And if I create a variable, can this one be read by a “third party” performer?

If you have better informations about variables please help me

Thank you

Comment: Obscurity is not the same thing as off topic - I suspect this would be fairly clear to someone actually familiar with the product in question.

Answer (score 0):

The variables must be declared in a component, a trigger for example. When you declare a variable `foo` of type `STRING` for example, if there is a performer in the `DO` action that accept a parameter of type `STRING` Atooma ask for the user if he wants to get the trigger output value or a new value. The control is let to the Atooma app from this point of view. The variable can be read by any performer so their scope is not the plug-in but the whole app. You don't need to call `getVariables()` as I said but you just need to declare a parameters, i.e the input, for your performer of a type compatible, the app will pass you the bundle with all the information needed and pre-filled.